# Filter entries of pandas dataframe based on presence (absence) of entries older than a date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` containing the test runs, dates and outcomes. it looks like this:

```
TestName;Date;IsPassed
test1;1/31/2017 9:44:30 PM;0
test1;1/31/2017 9:39:00 PM;0
test1;1/31/2017 9:38:29 PM;1
test1;1/31/2017 9:38:27 PM;1
test2;10/31/2016 5:05:02 AM;0
test3;12/7/2016 8:58:36 PM;0
test3;12/7/2016 8:57:19 PM;0
test3;12/7/2016 8:56:15 PM;0
test4;12/5/2016 6:50:49 PM;0
test4;12/5/2016 6:49:50 PM;0
test4;12/5/2016 3:23:09 AM;1
test4;12/4/2016 11:51:29 PM;1
```

I want to be able to find out the test names that don't have runs before or after a specified date.

Of course I can go like this:

- Identify all unique test names
- For each of them figure out their min and max dates
- Based on those add the respective rows to a new `DataFrame`

But is there any way to do that natively with Pandas, without explicit for loops?

**Update**

Based on the solution by @jezrael let's say I want to keep only the test runs that happened only in 2016. Then I have to do like this?

```
idx = test_runs.groupby('TestName').Date.agg(['idxmax']).stack().unique()
selected = test_runs.loc[idx].Date < pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')
tests = test_runs.loc[idx].loc[selected].TestName
print(test_runs[test_runs.TestName.isin(tests)])
```

Output:

```
TestName                Date  IsPassed
4     test2 2016-10-31 05:05:02         0
5     test3 2016-12-07 20:58:36         0
6     test3 2016-12-07 20:57:19         0
7     test3 2016-12-07 20:56:15         0
8     test4 2016-12-05 18:50:49         0
9     test4 2016-12-05 18:49:50         0
10    test4 2016-12-05 03:23:09         1
11    test4 2016-12-04 23:51:29         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `groupby` with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and 
[`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) for return `index` values of `min` and `max` dates, then reshape to `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Also is necessary remove duplicates by [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) for one `row` groups like `test2`.

Last select all rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
idx = df.groupby('TestName').Date.agg(['idxmin','idxmax']).stack().unique()
print (idx)
[ 3  0  4  7  5 11  8]

selected = df.loc[idx]
print (selected)
   TestName                Date  IsPassed
3     test1 2017-01-31 21:38:27         1
0     test1 2017-01-31 21:44:30         0
4     test2 2016-10-31 05:05:02         0
7     test3 2016-12-07 20:56:15         0
5     test3 2016-12-07 20:58:36         0
11    test4 2016-12-04 23:51:29         1
8     test4 2016-12-05 18:50:49         0
```

---

If need sorted `Index` add [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), because output of `unique` is `numpy array`.

```
print (df.loc[np.sort(idx)])
   TestName                Date  IsPassed
0     test1 2017-01-31 21:44:30         0
3     test1 2017-01-31 21:38:27         1
4     test2 2016-10-31 05:05:02         0
5     test3 2016-12-07 20:58:36         0
7     test3 2016-12-07 20:56:15         0
8     test4 2016-12-05 18:50:49         0
11    test4 2016-12-04 23:51:29         1
```

EDIT:

Your code looks nice, only some improvements was added:

```
idx = test_runs.groupby('TestName').Date.agg(['idxmin','idxmax']).stack().unique()
#get output to variable, then not need select twice  
df1 = test_runs.loc[idx]
#cast to datetime is not necessary
selected = df1['Date'] < '2017-01-01'
#for selecting in DataFrame is used df[index_val, column_name]
tests = df1.loc[selected, 'TestName']
#for better performance in large df was add unique
print(test_runs[test_runs.TestName.isin(tests.unique())])
   TestName                Date  IsPassed
4     test2 2016-10-31 05:05:02         0
5     test3 2016-12-07 20:58:36         0
6     test3 2016-12-07 20:57:19         0
7     test3 2016-12-07 20:56:15         0
8     test4 2016-12-05 18:50:49         0
9     test4 2016-12-05 18:49:50         0
10    test4 2016-12-05 03:23:09         1
11    test4 2016-12-04 23:51:29         1
```

Comment: Thanks! That's quite close to what I need. Let's say my task is to have only the runs that happened later than Nov. 01 2016(leaving out test2). Do I have to use something like this: `idx = test_runs.groupby('TestName').Date.agg(['idxmax']).stack().unique()
    

selected = test_runs.loc[idx].Date > pd.to_datetime('2016-11-01')
    
tests = test_runs.loc[idx].loc[selected].TestName
    
print(test_runs[test_runs.TestName.isin(tests)])`

Comment: I am not sure if understand, but it seems you can simply use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on output. Please check last edit of answer.

Comment: Well, it's a bit trickier. After I got the `selected` I need to go back to the _original_ dataframe and keep only the selected test names, but all the dates. I will update the question in a minute

Comment: I edit answer, please check it. I think your code is super.